# rage to table on all sheets

Tags: vba, excel

With the following VBA I am trying to loop through all sheets (except the two mentioned) and insert a table in the range A2005toAD3005:

```
For Each wsvar5 In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    With wsvar5
        If wsvar5.Name <> "timekeeper code" And wsvar5.Name <> "Bill Date" Then
            .ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A2005:AD3005"), , xlYes).ListObjects.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"
        End If
    End With
Next wsvar5
End Sub
```

This works for the first sheet and then stops and throws up the following error:

[Run-time error '1004': A table cannot overlap another table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfYKv.png)

This does not overlap any tables, as it works on the first sheet and all other sheets are in the same format.

Comment: Could you post your real code please as that clearly won't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing following line

```
.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A2005:AD3005"), , xlYes).ListObjects.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"
```

to

```
.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, .Range("A2005:AD3005"), , xlYes).TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium9"
```